# Sort query by array size (MongoDB & NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to sort this query by array size. Every document on this collection has an array of other objects, what I need to do is:

1. I need to filter this array of objects to retrieve only the ones where Date is greater than X
2. Then I need to sort them by the array size.

   ```
    const sales = await SaleSchema.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        "sales.saleDate": {
          $gte: new Date(Date.now() - 1 * 60 * 1000)
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        "contract": 1,
        "description": 1,
        "image": 1,
        "title": 1,
        "totalSupply": 1,
        sales: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$sales",
            as: 'sale',
            cond: {
              $gte: ['$$sale.saleDate', new Date(Date.now() - 1 * 60 * 1000)]
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        "arraySize": {
          "$size": "$sales"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        "arraySize": 1
      }
    },
    {
      $limit: 10
    }
   ]);
   ```

It is not working, I had a very similar query that was working, but when I created this filter for the sales array, that stopped working and I need to remake the query, but this one is not working tho..

Comment: It would be helpful if you give sample docs & point out which docs are not being retrieved as expected or what's the issue is!

Comment: SaleSchema has an array of objects (sales). Each object of this array, has a created date for example, what I need to do is to retrieve all the SaleSchema with the array of objects where the date is greater than X and then sort it by the array size.

Comment: So let's suppose I have 2 SaleSchemas, where the first one has 10 sales on the array (but only 5 have the date greater than X), while the second one has 8 sales on the array (but only 3 have the date greater than X).

It will sort like this:
first saleschema - has 5 elements on the array
second saleschema - has 3 elements on the array